# How do I replace new line and space in <tr> <td>?

Tags: html, bash, sed, replace

I need to create calendar in table (html) use `<tr>` `<td>` `<th>` replace space and new line in bash script.

I use this code:

```
cal | sed -e 's/ /<td>/g' >> "file.html"
cat "file.html" | sed 's/\n/<tr>/g' >> "file.html"
```

How can I fix this? In the html site, the result looks in one line.

I need this calendar looks like in the terminal:

`Январь 2018

Вс Пн Вт Ср Чт Пт Сб

    1  2  3  4  5  6

 7  8  9 10 11 12 13

14 15 16 17 18 19 20

21 22 23 24 25 26 27

28 29 30 31`

and i have this result in html file :http://screenshot.ru/upload/image/aIQK

Comment: That's invalid HTML. You need to replace every space with `</td><tr>`, and every newline with `</tr><tr>`.

Comment: Also, you'll want to redirect to a *different* file the second time (with `>`, not `>>`), because otherwise it will be duplicated.

Comment: how it looks like in code?

Comment: also i create two files when i write code html and paste before this code and after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed and BSD cal:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 cal -h | sed '1{s|^|<html><table>\n<tr><th colspan="7">|;s|$|</th></tr>|};2,${s|\(..\) |<td>\1</td>|g;s|^|<tr>|;s|$|</tr>|};$s|$|\n</table></html>|'
```

> `-h`: Turns off highlighting of today

Output:

```
<html><table>
<tr><th colspan="7">    January 2018      </th></tr>
<tr><td>Su</td><td>Mo</td><td>Tu</td><td>We</td><td>Th</td><td>Fr</td><td>Sa</td> </tr>
<tr><td>  </td><td> 1</td><td> 2</td><td> 3</td><td> 4</td><td> 5</td><td> 6</td> </tr>
<tr><td> 7</td><td> 8</td><td> 9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td> </tr>
<tr><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td> </tr>
<tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td> </tr>
<tr><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>  </td> </tr>
<tr><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>  </td> </tr>
</table></html>
```

Comment: thanks it works.
do i need to create a file with body html, and paste that code before bash and after?