# How do i replace new line and space in <td><tr> with sed for every month calendar?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sed

I use this code and this is works only for January,how can I create script with `sed` for every month?

```
var='<table>\n<tr><th colspan="7">'
cal -h | sed '1{s|^|'"${var}"'|;s|$|</th></tr>|};2,${s|\(..\) |<td>\1</td>|g;s|^|<tr>|;s|$|</tr>|};$s|$|\n</table>|' >> file.html
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded in single quotes.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Is this the continuation of [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510133/how-do-i-replace-new-line-and-space-in-tr-td#comment84016387_48510593) from yesterday?

Comment: yes is continuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with 3 months:

```
 for m in {1..3}
 do
   cal -m $m -h | sed '1{s|^|'"${var}"'|;s|$|</th></tr>|};2,${s|\(..\) |<td>\1</td>|g;s|^|<tr>|;s|$|</tr>|};$s|$|\n</table>|'
 done
```